# How pass JSON file path as run time argument?

Tags: python, json

Can anyone guide me on how can I pass the JSON file path as run time argument to main.py file? 
this code from GitHub https://github.com/ganesh-karthick/TwitterUserRanker

```
helpText = "Usage: \n python main.py  -f , --file=<InputJSONFile> \n[optional] -t , --topXUsers=<number>"
```

**I'm trying with this:**

```
helpText = "Usage: \n python main.py  -f , --file=/Users/RawanAbdullah/Downloads/TwitterUserRankerMaster/marssample.json \n[optional] -t , --topXUsers=<number>"
```

**The output:**

I know it may be very easy but I am a bit new to python

Comment: **The output:**

Usage: 
python main.py  -f , --file=<InputJSONFile> 
[optional] -t , --topXUsers=<number>
Usage: main.py [options]

main.py: error: Filename not given

Comment: Are you trying to write the python code that will be passed the file path, or are you trying to write the code to pass the file path?

Comment: Also, what's the code you're currently using?

Comment: @EdWard I want to pass the JSON file as argument .. you can check here for full program https://github.com/ganesh-karthick/TwitterUserRanker . Thank you so much for a quick reply